# __doPostBack not able to call gridView_RowCommand code behind function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, dopostback

I am having below code

Javscript

```
 var tempRowId;
 function handleResetButton(rowId) {            
            tempRowId = rowId;
            openPopUp(); //which opens a customize pop up div box
 }

//when user triggers the Confirm Button in the customize pop up div box, will call doPostBack()
function doPostBack() {
     var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= gridView.ClientID %>');
     var row = gridView.rows[tempRowId];

     // Set the command arguments
     row.cells[0].innerHTML ="Reset";
     __doPostBack(gridView.id, 'RowCommand$' + tempRowId);                                         
 }
```

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" runat="server"
            CellSpacing="0" Style="max-width: 100%; font-size: 100%;"
            OnRowDataBound='gridView_RowDataBound' AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand" ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyNames="AccountId"
            UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" ShowFooter="False">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ffffe0" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" FooterStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnReset" Style="padding: 0px; margin: 0 10px 0 0; width: 24px; height: 24px; border: 1px solid #000000"
                            ImageUrl="../Script/Masters/images/refresh.png" ToolTip="Reset" CommandName="Reset" 
                           OnClientClick='<%# "handleResetButton("+ Container.DataItemIndex +");return false;" %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code behind

```
    protected void gridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        var rowNo = row.RowIndex;
        var dataKey = gridView.DataKeys[rowNo];

        int accountId= Convert.ToInt32(dataKey.Value.ToString());


        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Reset":
                   //RUN CODE LOGIC
                break;

        }
    }
```

To briefly explain on this, when use clicks on the Reset button, it will prompt a customized pop up div box to prompt confirmation, and when user click on the confirm button, it will run the doPostBack() javascript function. I checked that it will run the doPostBack() but it seems to not running C# code behind logic on this. Is there something that i missed out or not handling correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I never really bother much with the row command. After all, dropping a simple button into a ListView, GridView, Repeater etc.?

You don't need to use row command, and it really does not help.
And using the GridView row command often forces you to put a bunch of "messy" case statements inside of the row command event. (which you don't need to use anyway).

Furthermore, with a simple button click event? Like all buttons, if your JavaScript returns true, then the button code (server side) will run. If your client side code returns false, then the code does not run.

So, for a GridView row button click, just use the click event of the button.

So, next we deal with how to return true, or false, and do this even when using asynchronous JavaScript code.

So, first up, how to use a button click and event in place of the "lame" row command.

So, say we have this simple list in a grid, and we have a delete button, and then we are to pop a jQuery.UI dialog to confirm (delete, or not).

So, we have this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
    Width="40%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/Reject80.png"
                    Width="32"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And dropping a button (or image button) inside of the GridView means we can't double click on the button (to create a click event). However, if in markup you type in OnClick= then you note intel-sense pops up a context dialog to create the event for code behind.

So, we now have this code for the Gridview:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton cmdDel = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cmdDel.NamingContainer;

        int RowIndex = gRow.RowIndex;
        int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[RowIndex]["ID"];

        // delete this row
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
            new SqlCommand(("DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID"));
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID;
        General.MyRstE(cmdSQL);

        LoadGrid();

    }
```

Now, note the use of sender (to get the button), and THEN note the use of naming container. This works for listview, gridview, repeater etc.

So, note how we don't have to pass the row index, note how we get the full GridView row, and note how we get the dataKeys PK database value.

So, above is quite nice, since if we add several buttons to that GridView/ListView etc.?

We don't mess around with row command.

Of course the above click would run the button code, and delete our row.

So, now let's add a client side dialog. This dialog can do quite much anything we want, but WHEN we confirm this dialog, we want the code behind (the image button click event code behind to run).

So, let's add the client side code and a jQuery.UI confirm dialog.

Of course like most dialogs and examples like sweet-alert etc.?

They do NOT wait or halt the code. So, we have to

Let the client side code run, returns false, display dialog.

If user hits cancel, then close dialog - do nothing.

If user accepts (confirms), then we set our flag = true, and THEN CLICK the SAME button again, and this time, since the routine returns true, then the server side (code behind runs).

We can't use a JavaScript promise and "await", but adding the above flag works just as well.

So, let's add the client side code + click to the button click, and we now have this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/Reject80.png"
                    Width="32"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return myconfirm(this)"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and the client side code is now this:

```
        <div id="myconfirmdiv" style="display:none">
            <h3><i>Delete this hotel?</i></h3>
            <i>(This can't be undone)</i>
        </div>

        <script>

            var myok = false
            function myconfirm(btn) {
                if (myok) {
                    return true
                }
                myDialog = $("#myconfirmdiv")

                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Delete?",
                    modal: true,
                    sizable: true,
                    width: '380',
                    closeText: "",
                    position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            myok = true
                            btn.click()
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                })
                return false
            }

        </script>
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, with above:

We don't have to care about messy row command - you rare need them, and they don't help you much.

You can pass the button, and click it, and as above shows, using "NamingContainer" gets you the grid row, and from that you can get the row index, which then gets you datakeys, and you can of course use find control against that row (for templated columns), or use .cells[] to get non templated cells from that GridView.

So above gets rid of the row command.

It gets rid of having to use __DoPostBack.

It gets rid of having to pass the "index" value in JavaScript.

It gets rid of having to try and pass some row index to the server (code behind).

And it gets rid of ...  well, I could keep on writing, but you get the idea here.

In above, I used jQuery, and also jQuery.UI which has the above "dialog" control. As noted, these dialogs don't halt code, so on first button click, the code displays the dialog, runs through, and returns false (so server side code does not run). If we hit "ok" to confirm, then flag is set true, and we click the SAME button again, and this time, it returns true, and thus the server side code behind runs.